# Kyoto Cabinet: is there a way to do a search for nearest key?

Tags: java, b-tree, kyotocabinet

I'd love to be able to use one of Kyoto Cabinet's tree datastructures, but I need the ability to return the nearest key.

Ie I have

```
1,100
3,500
7,1000
```

And given 2, I'd return 1.

Is this possible? If not, what is a lightweight, high speed alternative turned to do exactly this?

Thanks

Comment: Would a lower_bound or upper_bound function be an alternative?  I'd love to know how to solve this problem!

Comment: I never found a good way to do this in Kyoto cabinet :(

Comment: The only way that I know is to write custom comparator in C++ and then maintain custom build of kc lib. You may also have to recompile java bindings. If you are still looking for the answer I can write a quick how-to.

Comment: write how-to, post here and to hackernews, profit :)

Answer (score 0):

Kyoto Cabinet has Cursor 
and you can find bigger, equal or lower key using Cursor in TreeDB.